# AppArmor - restrict a directory by default (whitelist)

Tags: permissions, apparmor

I'm looking into AppArmor and from what I have seen, it seems like it allows access to everything by default and only puts access restrictions to application for which a profile has been created.

Is it possible to do opposite? - to deny access to a specific directory by default system wide and only allow access to it if it has been added in an application profile?

Example: You have some documents and you only want the document editor application to be able to access them. You create a profile for the document editor application, but do not have to bother blocking other apps from accessing it because it's restricted by default.